# Best practice for injecting DAO's

Tags: java, jpa, cdi, dao

I am in a process of paying my [Technical Debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) and one of the problem I have facing is the uses of DAO's with CDI injection.

I did write a blog about [DAO injection](http://theelitegentleman.blogspot.com/2014/04/daos-as-ejbs-you-are-doing-it-wrong.html) (using CDI, of course) and it works wonders and I will use the reference of the blog for my question. I am now in a situation where I have so many database tables (normalized, of course) and creating DAO's for each tables is not the issue. The issue is when a service (let's assume and EJB Session Bean) has "references" to many DAO's, like in the example below:

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerServiceEJB implements CustomerServiceLocal, CustomerServiceRemote, CustomerService {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomerServiceEJB.class.getName());

 @Inject @JPADAO
 private CustomerDAO customerDAO; 

 @Inject @JPADAO
 private CustomerAccountDAO customerAccountDAO;

 @Inject @JPADAO
 private CustumerCredentialDAO customerCredentialDAO;

 //And rougly 15 more DAO's.
}
```

As you can see, if we need to use various DAO's, the class has "instances" of all DAO's and that means that the CDI container will have to inject all of them prior to being used.

One solution I came up with was to create a `DAOManager` where all references of the DAO's are listed in the manager.

Example:

```
public interface DAOManager {

    public CustomerDAO getCustomerDAO(); 

    public CustomerAccountDAO getCustomerAccountDAO();

    public CustumerCredentialDAO getCustomerCredentialDAO();

    //Etc
}
```

And it's JPA's representation:

```
@JPADAO
public class JPADAOManager implements DAOManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public CustomerDAO getCustomerDAO() {
        return new JPACustomerDAO(entityManager);
    }

    //Etc...
}
```

Finally, in `CustomerServiceEJB`, I can inject the DAO as follows:

```
@Inject @JPADAO
private DAOManager daoManager;
```

My question: Is my approach correct? If not, what is the best approach? Also, what do I need to take into consideration when using DAO's with CDI? *Added question:* Should `JPADAOManager` return a DAO in lazy-loading fashion?

Comment: *As you can see, if we need to use various DAO's, the class has "instances" of all DAO's and that means that the CDI container will have to inject all of them prior to being used.* And how is that a problem? CDI offers you dependency injection, which tremendously helps testing your code, avoiding writing useless factories, and identifying your dependencies. The DAOs are the dependencies of your service. Leave it as it is. It's perfectly OK. If a service has too many DAO dependencies, it's simply a sign that your service has too many responsibilities and should be refectored.

Comment: @JB Nizet these are the types of responsibilities that can't be ignored. Typical example is user authentication: One will need to extract a password salt and verify whether the password entered matches the hashed password stored in DB. Also, maintain a log of all logon attempts and invalid passwords as well as setting user status (LOGGED IN, LOGGED OUT), etc. Now, to encapsulate all this in a `DAOManager` will mean a cleaner code on the service layer rather than have many DAO's on the service. It's part of the refactoring process but it requires adding an additional layer. Is it good/bad?

Comment: How is that cleaner code? Instead of having a well defined and identifiable set of DAOs on which you depend, you rely on a God object allowing to gain access to every DAO in your system, and are forced to use lookup methods (getFooDao(), getBarDao()) instead of directly using a field. And in your test, you're forced to mock all these lookup methods instead of relying on your native mocking framework support for DI (`@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` in Mockito, for example). What you see as a problem is actually a good thing.

Comment: @JB Nizet understood. I will then not consider creating a `DAOManager` in this case and carry AS IS. I will leave this question opened to those who are have similar thoughts as well.

Comment: The whole concept is a question of OO priciples. More precisely: Interface Segregation Principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). By this you might not inject dao-per-table DAOs but you would rethink what is the minimal interface you need and you would inject a class implementing that simple interface.